# Passing the wildcard * unevaluated to inner commands

Tags: bash, wildcard

I'm writing a script that requires me to use an unevaluated `*`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
show() {
    for file in $(find . -name $1); do
        echo $file
    done
}
```

If I run `show *.pdf`, the code will only look for PDFs in the current directory, and pass them into `find . -name`.

What I need is for the wildcard to be transferred to `find` unevaluated, so that it will look for PDFs recursively in the current folder.

My current solution involves doing this:

```
show() {
    for file in $(find . -name "*$1"); do
        echo $file
    done
}
```

Which lets me write `show .pdf`, and that's fine, except nearly all bash commands that allow wildcards use the `*` operator. So for the sake of keeping it consistent with the rest of the system.

Is there a way for me to do this? I'm pulling my hairs out over this issue.

I've also tried `show "*.pdf"` but that yields the exact same result.

**NOTE**: It might look strange that I'm just echoing the result, when I could just have it run `find . -name "*.pdf"`. That's true, but this is the first step in a larger script. I want to get this to work before continuing.

Comment: Quote the argument to your function and quote it inside the function. `show '*.pdf'` , `find . -name "$1"`. Also you shouldn't really be parsing the results of find in a for loop since that opens you up to more shell interpretation of special chars/whitespace.

Comment: Be sure to read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); you can't reliably iterate over the output of `find` with a `for` loop like this.

Comment: @chepner then what would be a better way to recursively iterate through all folders in a folder? I don't necessarily know how deeply nested the directories are `find` ignores that

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4, you might not need `find` at all; use `for f in **/*.pdf; do`. Otherwise, use a `while` loop that reads from a pipe or a process substitution; see the linked page for details.

Comment: this still doesn't solve the issue of the wildcard expanding too early